# Event after submit - prestashop

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, prestashop, e-commerce

I want to save an image the same name of the id

1. create user in DB -> submit.

   after submit I want to use the same id for the image
2. create an image in the folder ( same id.jpg)

   I work in this code right now

if ($_FILES['CustomerImage']['name'] != "") {

```
 $id = Tools::getValue('id_customer') != '' ? Tools::getValue('id_customer') : "22";
if (!Customer::saveCustomerImage($_FILES['CustomerImage'], $id)) {
    $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('The image seller format is incorrect.', 'AdminCustomersController');
}
```

}

When does the update work fine, the problem when creating a new user ID = empty

please help

Comment: have a look here :https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/resources/products/ i think the two red X for quantity meaning you cant use it.

Comment: I think you will need to use the stocks webservice https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/resources/stocks/